# Combining several columns without concatenate MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to combine several columns from many tables into 1 column. However, I do not want to concatenate them. I want the values to be inserted into an empty fields below the already inserted values. Is there a way to do this without using a ton of SELECT statements?

For example, I have 4 columns from 13 tables. I want these put into one column in a new table.

Right now the only way I can figure out to do this is like this

```
INSERT INTO softwareid (software)
SELECT column1
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1
FROM table2
UNION ALL
SELECT column1
FROM table3
UNION ALL
SELECT column1
FROM table4
```

Doing it this way means I need to create more SELECT statements for every column. Is there a way to combine all of that?

Comment: That's the way to do it - brute force typing. Are you just looking for a more elegant solution or is there another reason you are asking for an additional solution?

Comment: @AgRizzo Ok thanks. I was mostly just wondering if there was a better more elegant way to do that. I'm a noob so I wasn't sure.